# Bootstrap table-responsive not working in a panel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, html-table

Following is my code using Twitter bootstrap 3.3.1. The table-responsive div located under a panel. It works when I reduce the width of the browser but it does not when I open it in my iPhone.

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       responsive table test
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 40%;" />
                <col style="width:30%;" />
                <col style="width:30%;" />
            </colgroup>
             <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> test 1 </th>
                    <th> test 2 </th>
                    <th> test 3 </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                 <td> ... </td>
                 <td> ... </td>
                 <td> ... </td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Shot in the dark...Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the head?

Comment: Does Bootlint ( https://github.com/twbs/bootlint ) flag any errors on your page?

Comment: Yes I have viewport meta in the head

Comment: cvrebert I haven't used bootlint